# Is there a way in MySQL to compare two rows of same column structure and find out which column values have changed?

Tags: mysql, compare

I have a problem where I need to compare two different rows of similar column structure and be able to find out which column values have changed?

Table A

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Carter |
| 2 | Jeff | Derney |

Table B

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Johnny | Carter |
| 2 | Jeff | Dunham |

Desired Output

| ID | PRIMARY_KEY | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John | Johnny |
| 2 | 2 | Derney | Dunham |

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id AS primary_key, 
       tableA.first_name AS old_value, 
       tableB.first_name AS new_value,
       'first name' AS altered_column
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id 
           AND tableA.first_name <> tableB.first_name 

UNION ALL

SELECT id, 
       tableA.last_name, 
       tableB.last_name,
       'last name'
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id 
           AND tableA.last_name <> tableB.last_name 

ORDER BY primary_key;
```